# Is there a method to use VBA to insert multiple images and insert them in order of selection through the dialog box?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm creating multiple reports with a ton of images (50+ images). I need to insert them in a specific order. I have a running script which opens a Dialog box and I can select the photos that I want, but when I press OK, it inserts the images in alphabetical order. I want them to be inserted in the order I select them from the dialog box.

I've tried to find methods relating to insertion methods in VBA. Nothing?

```
Sub InsertSelectedPixs()
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim picPath As String
Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rep As Variant

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

With fd
.InitialFileName = "*"
.AllowMultiSelect = True
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Images", "*.png; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.tif"

If .Show = -1 Then

For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
Set MyPic = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(vrtSelectedItem)
picName = Right(vrtSelectedItem, Len(vrtSelectedItem) - InStrRev(vrtSelectedItem, "\"))

MyPic.Select
MyPic.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
MyPic.Width = CentimetersToPoints(7.25)
Selection.MoveDown wdLine
Selection.TypeText Chr(11)
Selection.InsertCaption Label:="Figure", Title:=". " & picName, Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow
Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
Selection.TypeText Chr(10)
Next vrtSelectedItem

Else
End If
End With

Set fd = Nothing

With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
.Execute FindText:=".jpg", ReplaceWith:="", Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
Selection.WholeStory
Dim oRange As Word.Range

If ActiveDocument.Range.Tables.Count <> 0 Then Exit Sub

Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Range

oRange.ConvertToTable Separator:=wdSeparateByParagraphs, Format:=wdTableFormatGrid1, NumColumns:=2

Set oRange = Nothing

End Sub
```

The images get imported into the Word doc in alphabetical order rather than the selected order during the selection screen (file dialog box)

Comment: I know this is not the ideal solution, and you might have already thought about it or gone that route... but since the FileDialog doesn't work the way you need it, maybe you can rename your pictures alphabetically, in the order you want them inserted? Alternatively, you would need to write your own file dialog, see a starting point [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/95b9254b-2555-4b1f-8ea4-9db6df58e9a6/open-file-dialog-multislection-order-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the `FileDialog` file picker is always going to return a [collection of selected items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog.selecteditems) that are sorted in the order that they appeared in the `FileDialog` (e.g., alphabetical by file name). It does not have a method to preserve the specific actions the user took to get to the final list of selections.

In order to solve this, you would need to build your own combo box function that added items to a collection each time the user selected one from the list. This would preserve the order of the user's choices and would enable you to do what you are looking for.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to start this?

Comment: @tmand6 Tacking on this question in a comment is "not done" on Stack Overflow - this is not a typical forum site, but a Q&A format. You could ask this in a new question, but in its present state the question would be "too broad" (review the information on asking questions in the site [help]). You'd need to make an effort and then ask when you hit a specific problem. If this answer basically answers your question as stated (which in my opinion it does) then it should be marked as the answer...

Comment: @tmand6 ...I suggest you start by looking for code that reads the content of a Folder, figure out how to pick up the file names in an array (there are LOTS of examples "out there"). Then research VBA UserForms and there combobox and listbox controls. It's possible to assign the content of an array to such a control. Once you have that, then look into how to get the order the user selects the items in the list.